# Completely stuck at transfering files from assets folder to sd card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am using following reference to transfer files from assets folder to sd card 
[How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard)
The problem with this approach is that it is transferring the file located at root i.e. assets folder only and onto sdcard folder only. I have tried other options also but i am completely stuck.

My folder structure is

[image]

I want to copy the whole default folder and copy it to /sdcard/myapp/themes/default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is to create zip file of the resources for. e.g. themes in this case(under assets) and then unzip it into sdcard. You can refer following url:[unzipping files with android](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)